# How do I remove checked nodes from a Kendo TreeView?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-treeview

Here's my configuration:

```
$(function()
{
    var data = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "../api/notifications/byuserid/10078261",
                contentType: "application/json"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                children: "notifications"
            }
        }
    });

    $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        dataSource: data,
        loadOnDemand: false,
        checkboxes: {
            checkChildren: true
        },
        dataTextField: ["notificationType", "NotificationDesc"]
    });
});
```

On the click event of the button "Delete," I want to remove all of the nodes that are checked.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#btnDelete').click(function()
    {
        var treeView = $('#treeview').data("kendoTreeView");
        var selectedNodes = treeView.select();
        //here's where im not sure what to do...
    });
});
```

The tree view is here in the markup (I know a mess... I'm the guy fixing all this mess right now):

```
<body onload=" Resize(); ">
   <form id="frmTake2Home" runat="server">
       <table class="main" style="border-style: hidden; padding: 0px">
          <td class="tbody">
             <table style="border-spacing: 0px; border-style: hidden; padding: 0px; vertical-align: top" width="100%" border="0">
              <tr>
                <td id="tdTreeView" valign="top" width="48%">
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2">
                    <div id="treeview"></div> //here's my kendo treeview
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var treeView = $('#treeview').data("kendoTreeView");             

    $('#btnDelete').on('click', function(){
        $('#treeview').find('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
            treeView.remove($(this).closest('.k-item'));
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks for the hand! unfortunately this removes the nodes based on node selection and NOT on CHECK box selection... how do I check the nodes based on their corresponding check box checks?

Comment: Ah! what's the class name attached to the checkboxes?

Comment: @Rj. Is that complete?

Comment: the markup is massive. just use the ID to find the treeview (<div id="treeview"></div>)